# How can I merge two X-Macros together?

Tags: c++, c, macros, x-macros

I have a lot of repetitive code that needs me to use different sets of data frequently in some function or some operation. i.e as shown below (the numbers and letters are just place holders, all i need to do is string two sets of data together using x macros)

```
a = 1
a = 2
a = 3
a = 4
.
.
.
```

then

```
b = 1
b = 2
b = 3
.
.
.
```

and

```
c = 1
c = 2
c = 3
.
.
.
```

I was trying to create an X-macro that combines the following two X-macros into one

```
//X-macro 1
#define SET_1 \
X(a) \
X(b) \
X(c) \
```

```
//X-macro 2
#define SET_2 \
X(1) \
X(2) \
X(3) \
X(4)
```

Any help?

Comment: C or C++? Decide, because C++ might offer alternatives not available in C...

Comment: How should the "combination" look like? [X-Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) usually only take one argument, so how should the two sets be combined? could you maybe provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how you're planning to use it & what the output should look like?

Comment: @Turtlefight the one I provided was the minimal example, I just removed all the unnecessary clutter. It looks something like this (with the clutter)
`regA = regA;
regA = regB;
regA = regC;
regA = regD;`
then 
`regB = regA;
regB = regB;
regB = regC;
regB = regD;` 
Basically I have to do this n times for n different registers which why i wanted an x-macro, so it becomes easy and maintainable as well

Comment: @Aconcagua it's c++

Comment: This extended example looks like one register receiving the values of all other ones. Second example might be flawed, you are writing `regB` to itself *after* having written `regA` to, so you'd effectively write `regA` to all others than `regA` itself...

Comment: Following the example given in the comments I'd rather write a function accepting one value which it writes to all those registers – note that by accepting the parameter by value you'd fix the possible flaw mentioned above as well... Might look like `void assignToAll(uint32_t value) { regA = value; regB = value; ... } called as `assignToAll(regA);`

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

```
#define X_abc(X,X2) \
X(a,X2) \
X(b,X2) \
X(c,X2)

#define X_1234(x,X2) \
X2(x,1) \
X2(x,2) \
X2(x,3) \
X2(x,4) 

#define SET(x,y)     x = y;
#define DEFINE(x,y)  int x = y;

X_abc(X_1234,DEFINE)
```

Comment: Can we do the above approach when we have different no of elements ?                                      `#define X_abc(X,X2) \
X(a,X2) \
X(b,X2) \
X(c,X2)`                                                                                                                                          `#define X_1234(x,X2) \
X2(x,1) \
X2(x,2) \
X2(x,3)`

Comment: @ro88: yes of course, I don't see a problem with that